# Bixby Capsule - Interacting with Existing Application?

Tags: bixby

I was thinking of creating a Bixby Capsule that interacts with the Google Keep (or Samsung Notes) app, and adds stuff to a list/new note. Is this possible?

If not, does anyone have any idea of what else would work if I wanted to store stuff in a list? Don't tell me I would need to have a public web server listening for input and I'd store stuff with the assistance of that. Ridiculous overkill IMO. Thanks for any info!

Comment: Here's a line from the Bixby Capsule Design Guidelines: "Bixby is not a voice command feature. It does not aim to allow users to control, navigate or manipulate apps with voice." That's understandable, so probably a Capsule interacting with Google Keep/Samsung Notes is not gonna happen. That's fine, I'm just wondering if it's possible to add/remove from a list in another way. Would I just store stuff in a .js file and read that into an array, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways that might help fulfill the task:

1. If the App has an API, such as Uber, you can use the API in capsule. Please read
   more about REST API in
   https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.js-actions
2. In case of a local app on the device, you would need to check if that app allow android deep-link and use punch-out function with a payload uri. Please read more in https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/result-view.app-launch

---

Actually... Current built-in Bixby already support add/delete notes to Samsung Notes by the utterance "Add a note that [content]" and remove all notes by "delete all notes".

Please give it a try.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I kinda figured there would be some sort of Notes integration but didn't know about the prompt for it. It indeed works, however each time I add something to Notes it creates a brand new note. Understandable but I'd like to add things to an existing note (or create a new one and keep adding to it). So it sounds like if I really wanted to do this, I might have to create my own Android app and then pass data along to it via the punch-out functionality with payload-uri, is that right?

Comment: There is the utterance "Edit Samsung note" that will open note for edit. But in general, it might be difficult to use built-in Bixby to perform complicated task with app. I am not sure how easy or difficult it is to create an app, but on capsule side, punch-out is straightforward. We have seen app developers created capsules to aid users with their app.